# Does NSURLConnection support HTTPS session resumption?

Tags: ssl, https, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection in an iOS app for making HTTPS connection to the server. I want to make those connections faster.

Does the framework support session resumption?

Comment: There is some discussion here which hints that the answer is yes: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2011/Apr/msg00026.html. But I too would like a more authoritative and clear-cut answer to this question.